# "Invalid object type conversion" error when trying

Tags: google-apps-script, type-conversion, google-forms

This code is supposed to prefill the date on google form, but I get an error:

> Exception: Invalid object type conversion: DATE. (row: 13, file: Code)

```
        function doGet(){

        //open your form

        var form = FormApp.openById("1m89CzaTzP5mIUvwdHbjOvaIoEWJ54N3vVf0LBl4RFIo");
        
        //get the questions

        var questions = form.getItems();
  
        //get the question where you want to prefill the date as an answer, e.g. first question

        var question1=questions[0];
  
        //get the current date

        var time=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-2000");
  
        //prefill form with current date

        var prefilledTime=form.createResponse().withItemResponse(question1.asTextItem().createResponse(time));  
 
        //Get the link to the prefilled form

        var URL=prefilledTime.toPrefilledUrl();
        
        //redirect to the prefilled form URL dynamically created above 

        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + URL + "\";</script>");

}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218494/discussion-on-question-by-aady-ahmed-invalid-object-type-conversion-error-when).

Answer (score 1):

[`getItems`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems) method returns an array of generic `Item` instances that need to be converted to their respective types, as contrary to what one might expect, `createResponse` method has different signatures for each `Item` type:

1. [`DateItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-item#createresponseresponse) and [`DateTimeItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-time-item#createresponseresponse) expect a `Date` as the only parameter
2. [`Duration`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/duration-item#createresponsehours,-minutes,-seconds) expects 3 `number`s (docs say `Integer`)
3. [`CheckBoxGridItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item#createresponseresponses) wants a matrix of `string`s (`string[][]` in docs)
4. [`CheckboxItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#createresponseresponses) and [`GridItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#createresponseresponses) only need a `string` array
5. [`MultipleChoiceItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createresponseresponse) accepts a `string`, as does [`ParagraphTextItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/paragraph-text-item#createresponseresponse) and, of course, so does [`TextItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#createresponseresponse)
6. [`ScaleNumber`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/scale-item#createresponseresponse) is happy with a `number`
7. [`TimeItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/time-item#createresponsehour,-minute) - 2 `number`s, representing hours and minutes

What's more, the types are fixed, so the only option available is converting from `Item` to the original item type (for example: `DateItem` > `Item` > `DateItem`). If you try to convert a `DateItem` to `TextItem` (which is exactly what you did), an "Invalid type conversion" error is thrown.

[`formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) method returns a `string` and judging from the screenshot you provided, the item is of type `DateItem`, therefore you need to call the [`asDateItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asdateitem) method, not `asTextItem` and pass the `new Date()` directly as the method signature suggests.